# "Joining" points in one mesh

Tags: edit-mode

Given: a mesh which forms one-n'th of a torus. I Alt-D-duplicate it, rotate the copy by 360°/n, and get the ends to meet up. Repeat n-1 times.

I have now a nicely symmetric object which I can edit further. This is not the problem.

The problem is that when I move a vertex at the border between copies, that nice alignment is destroyed. Obviously I cannot join the corresponding vertices; it's the same underlying mesh, after all..

Thus, how can I keep them in sync while editing? Repeating the edit steps on the "other" side is tedious, and snap-to-vertex doesn't help much either.

To clarify: I want to create a closed object with n-fold symmetry which stays closed and symmetric, no matter which vertex/edge/face I move. A normal torus will not stay symmetric. A 1/nth-torus with n-1 360°/n-rotated copies will not stay closed when I move a vertex/edge/face at the border.

Comment: One point to note is that the term for a point in Blender is called a "vertex", not "vortex".

Comment: I think you should be using the "screw" modifier for this.

Comment: Are you simply talking about removing overlapping vertices? if so, **A** to select all vertices, then **W > Removing Doubles**.

Answer (score 4):

You could merge the vertices by invoking the *Remove Doubles* operator

[image]

In your case you could create the torus without duplicated vertices, starting with an e.g. an 1/8th

[image]

By rotating using the 
[*Spin Tool*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Duplicating/Spin)  <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> in *Edit Mode*

[image]

Comment: Alt-R does not seem to do anything in my version of Blender. In any case, did you actually try moving e.g. the top-most vertex after this? Did that action leave a hole in the torus?

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs You need to be in Edit Mode, and yes you won't have duplicated vertices with the settings used in the image.

Answer (score 3):

I don't completely understand the problem you are encountering, but here are a few things you might try:

1. While in Edit mode, before you start modeling (such as duplicating your torus sections) turn on "Automatically merge vertices moved to the same location":

   [image]

   This makes sure you won't have double, non-merged vertices in the same spot, thus you won't have to use Remove Doubles later on.
2. When you use <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the torus section, you are creating what is called a Linked Duplicate. With Linked Duplicates, whenever you modify the section, **ALL** of the sections will be effected, as shown here:

   [image]

   However, if you don't want this to happen, use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to create non-linked Duplicates. With these kinds of Duplicates, when you edit one, the others remain unedited, as shown here:

   [image]

If you want to learn more about the differences between Duplicates and Linked Duplicates, you can read more about them here:  http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication

Comment: Thanks, but I do know the difference between a duplicate and a linked duplicate. The point is that auto-merging vertices does not work for linked duplicates. In your first linked-duplicate example, you moved a random vertex on the surface of the quarter-torus. That obviously works. However, moving a vertex on the very top (or left etc.), where the duplicates join will leave a hole.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an *Array modifier*:

1. Add a torus and delete three quarters of it:

   [image]
2. Add an empty and rotate it 90° around the Z (or whatever axis to which the torus is aligned)

   [image]
3. Add an array modifier to the torus, with *Object offset* enabled and the empty selected as the offset object:

   [image]

By using the 3D cursor as the pivot point and being suitably careful about how you move your vertices maintaining a manifold mesh shouldn't be too hard. Another advantage to the array modifier is that it updates in edit mode.